# Extracting product entities from a text

Tags: java, named-entity-recognition

I was trying to use a **Named Entity Recognizer** for extracting the product names from a given text.

ie,
  Input text : " Google makes google fit "
  Expected output : **Google Fit** (Product)

Is there any tool already available for this ?
(I tested **Alchemy API** which is not relevant for extracting product names)
If no such tools are present , How can I build my own a training model for accomplishing this ?

Answer (score 1):

The Apache OpenNLP library is a machine learning based toolkit for the processing of natural language text.

It supports the most common NLP tasks, such as tokenization, sentence segmentation, part-of-speech tagging, named entity extraction, chunking, parsing, and coreference resolution. These tasks are usually required to build more advanced text processing services. OpenNLP also includes maximum entropy and perceptron based machine learning.

Some Examples: [Click Here](http://www.programcreek.com/2012/05/opennlp-tutorial/)